# Java LWJGL - How can I add water to my 3d world?

Tags: java, shaders, lwjgl, water

The title says it all, how can I implement a simplistic water system into my game? I am using Java LWJGL and OpenGL glsl shaders. I am still fairly new to game programming, and a complete noob in the use of shaders so some guidance and a thorough explanation would be great!

Comment: This is a very broad topic. There's many ways to render water, depending on what you're trying to do _specifically_. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you could just start with a plane/quad with a static/animated water texture. From there you could maybe make an animated mesh with a texture. If you want to get into shaders, then you'd have to research the optical physics of water before trying to develop any

Comment: Thanks, do you know whereci can find information about this

Comment: Basically just googling around. Theres plenty of articles from academic to pragmatic